# GTK+ 2.24. How to use unicode symbols in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, unicode, encoding, gtk

I want to have some unicode labels in GTK+ interface windows. How can I use it? Code:

```
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "ŲŪ");
```

Does not show anything in the window title bar so I guess it is because of encoding.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and C compiler from Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0 which is outdated C99 compiler.

---

Update:
I found this article http://owenshepherd.net/2010/the-sorry-state-of-unicode-in-c which claims that there is very poor support of unicode in C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to use Unicode code points directly inside C, you can use the C escaped octal form; for instance, the Copyright sign © is `\302\251`.

this table should help you converting code points: http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct

Comment: Great, thank you! I would like to emphasize that it is important to remove 0 from the beginning of the code "0302 0251", because "\0302\0251" gives different character.

Comment: @Benas That's because the octal escapes can't be more than three octal digits, by having a leading 0 and then three digits, only the 0 and the two leftmost digits are part of the escape. Contrary to popular belief, the leading 0 is not needed.